# A MarkLogic XCC library throws a type initializer exception only on QA

Tags: c#, .net, marklogic

My .NET app talks to MarkLogic via XCC. I'm executing some DB-side XQuery when the error occurs. Running locally, this is fine but in QA I get:

> The type initializer for 'com.marklogic.xcc.impl.handlers.ServerErrorParser' threw an exception.

It's an ASP.NET MVC app on IIS on Windows and talks to MarkLogic on CentOS.

This is QA, I know the answer and am unsatisfied with other chat buried in forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can occur when a required library is missing on the target environment. The .NET MarkLogic XCC components are actually Java wrapped by IKVM, it's likely that you don't have references to all the DLLs in your project and are thus not publishing them to IIS.

Make sure your project references the MarklogicXcc.dll, xcccore.dll and *all* IKVM DLLs.

The situation is that your XQuery probably encounters some environmental difference, some different data or something that's causing the query to throw.

The XCC pipeline wants to parse the error but when it tries to load the ServerErrorParser type it encounters a missing library dependency.

When running locally, the XQuery might be running fine and thus never exercising the XCC code path that needs stuff from the missing DLL.

Comment: And then put a story on your backlog to move to using MarkLogic over REST since XCC should no longer be used.